# running 2 windows using vmware

Tags: windows, vmware, operating-systems

I have 2 HDD. Both have windows OS.

Is it possible to boot into one OS and then use vmware (or any other tool) to open or boot into OS on another HDD.

Basically I want to use both windows but not boot into them separately again and again.

Is it possible..? and how to go for it?

Comment: What has your research shown you so far? What have you tried? Where did it fail? We can help you with specific problems, but entire tutorial-on-demand is not what this site is for.

Comment: You can convert (VMware Converter) one machine to a virtual machine and do what you propose. I do that with various machines. 4 windows running normally.

Comment: wonderful John thanks...This was all I wanted to know... vmware vonverter.. i will look into it :)

Comment: Just to be clear: when you convert it, you won't be opening or booting what's installed on HDD2. You will create an entirely new machine, an independent virtual copy of the installation on the HDD2. Nothing you do on the VM will be reflected on the HDD2.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned, you will need to convert one of your Windows installations to run as a VM. Depending on the hypervisor you choose (VMware or Hyper-V) there are different tools to perform the conversion. VMware Converter is one of them.
https://www.vmware.com/products/converter.html
As an alternative, you can use StarWind V2V Converter, which can do a P2V conversion to a hypervisor of your choice.
https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-v2v-converter